# issue running Jitsi-meet [ jicofo component ]?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, webrtc, jitsi

I have followed the manual-install steps and when I try to run the components 
jitsi-videobridge-linux-x86-971 and jicofo

I have the following exception :

```
    Jicofo 2017-07-23 11:30:33.985 SEVERE: [30] org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain.call().278 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), host:10.64.5.89, port:5347
org.xmpp.component.ComponentException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponent.connect(ExternalComponent.java:272)
        at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponentManager.addComponent(ExternalComponentManager.java:221)
        at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponentManager.addComponent(ExternalComponentManager.java:201)
        at org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain$3.call(ComponentMain.java:270)
        at org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain$3.call(ComponentMain.java:255)
        at org.jitsi.retry.RetryStrategy$TaskRunner.run(RetryStrategy.java:193)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:580)
        at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponent.connect(ExternalComponent.java:151)
        ... 12 more
```

giving that the video bridge is working and the configuration is correct

Regards,

Comment: Please show your code that is causing the exception. Also provide a `netstat` of listening ports for `10.64.5.89`.

Comment: @jww there is no code , this is a jitsi-meet component , netstat :
$ netstat | grep 5347
tcp        0      0 localhost:45590         localhost:5347          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:5347          localhost:45590         ESTABLISHED

Comment: Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: AnyUpdate , is there any configuration that I must check in order to fix connection refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue by adding --host to the command that runs jicofo , 
so my command host=localhost

Regards,